# run a proccess in background without delay the php application

Tags: php, post, curl, http-post, http-status-code-404

am new in php development

i sending curl php post to external url and i want to check if the stats of post is not equal 200 the php application should send the same post and same data after 15 min ,i do it and it works excellent, but my problem is i using sleep(); function to delay the post for 15 min and my application be busy until sleep function is die, i want to ask if i can do this case in background without delay in application.

this is my code :

```
<?php
$command = $Curl_Session = curl_init('http:www.example.com');
$command .= curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$command .= curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "contentID=".$newsId."&contentType=".$content_type."&contentTitle=".$newsTitle."&contentBody=".urlencode(wordwrap($newsBody,true))."&contentOfToday=".$news_today."&contentTime=".$date_created."&contentIMGURL=".$news_image."&contentURL=".$bath_to_share."");
$command .= curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$command .= curl_exec ($Curl_Session);
sleep(10000);
shell_exec(sprintf('%s > /dev/null 2>&1 &', $command));
?>
```

thank you all 
Best Regards

Comment: How about running your script with cron every 15 minutes? Why are you choking your server this way?

Comment: what the best way to solve this problem

Comment: my suggestion is to use cron unless you have to do some logging after user aborts

Comment: Remove that sleep() function and create a cron entry like this: `*/15 * * * * /path/to/your/script.php` to run it every 15 minutes.

Comment: thank you @kodeart but i dont want to run this cron every 15 min i want this proccess run if the post status is not equal 200 for example 404

Comment: You can take a different approach. You can keep track of post statuses in database (maybe by running a script through a cron) and if != 200 send the post using curl. Or after posting the content, if status is != 200, store it temporarily in a database and process after desired time. I don't know your use case here. But please make some more research how to use curl, this is very weird code :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use "[ignore_user_abort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)(true)"

So the script will continue to work (keep an eye on script duration, perhaps add "[set_time_limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)(0)")

But a warning here: You will not be able to stop a script with these two lines:

```
ignore_user_abort(true); 
set_time_limit(0);
```

Except you can directly access the server and kill the process there! (Been there, done an endless loop, calling itself over and over again, made the server come to a screeching stop, got shouted at...)

[Also this url may help](http://braincrafted.com/php-background-processes/)

Comment: For the OP script, this is exactly what you're advising: destroy your server.